# Alinhamento de input mesma row utilizando validação de formulário

Tags: html, react, input, css

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário de cadastro em React, e para validação dos `input`'s utilizo o Yup.

Na terceira row do formulário tenho 3 `input`'s, quando o Yup faz a validação e insere as mensagens de notificação eles ficam desalinhados, segue imagem:

[image: Campos desalinhados]

Segue o CSS do form:

```css
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;

    label {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    input {
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

      div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        input {
          width: 240px;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em

```
form div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
```

Troque por

```
form div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
```

O `flex-start` vai alinhar os elemento interno no topo do *container*, o `space-between` acaba alinhando um elemento em cada canto do *container* gerando esse espaço entre o texto e o `input`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código da imagem acima:**

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: teal;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-basis: calc(100%/3);
}
.box{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 35px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
Com justify-content: flex-start;

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box">label 1</div>
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">msg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box">label 2</div>
      <div class="box">msg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box">label 3</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">msg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado.

Comment: @DavidBorelli obrigado meu jovem, qq dúvida comenta ai que tento te ajudar! Abs

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade `justify-content: space-between;` posiciona os dois elementos em cada extremidade da div (no seu caso, extremidades verticais).

Pelo seu CSS, você está aplicando ela nas divs filhas diretas do form, que está afetando for hereditariedade as subdivs dessas divs.

Basta alterar essas subdivs acrescentando `justify-content: flex-start;` (veja a linha comentada com `/* AQUI!! */` no código abaixo):

```
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;

    label {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    input {
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding-left: 15px;
    }

    div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

      div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start; /* AQUI!! */

        input {
          width: 240px;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

> Agora, repare que quando a mensagem é exibida, há uma quebra no grid,
>   fazendo com que uma div encoste na outra. Para resolver isso,
>   acrescente `flex: 1;` abaixo da propriedade que sugeri acima. Isso
>   força com que as 3 divs mantenham a largura **fixa** e **iguais** e não encoste uma na
>   outra.

**Veja um exemplo:**

*Alterei a largura dos inputs para 140px apenas para ilustrar.*

```css
form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
}

form label {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
      font-size: 14px;
}

form input {
      height: 30px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding-left: 15px;
}

form div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
}

form div div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        flex: 1;
}

form div div input {
          width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div>
      <div>
         <label>Idade</label>
         <input type="text">
          <div>mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem</div>
      </div>
     <div>
         <label>Peso</label>
         <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Altura</label>
         <input type="text">
          <div>mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem mensagem</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Veja como fica sem as propriedades sugeridas acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recomendo você guardar o **[Guia Completo sobre flexbox](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/)**, que é muito útil para referências, consultas e tirar dúvidas.

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo, porém ao invés de usar o flex: 1 e definir um width fixo no input, na div da row eu coloquei width 100%, depois capturei a div do input do meio e coloquei margem nas extremidades laterais.

Comment: Pode ser também. Minha resposta foi uma sugestão e um norte para vc formatar as divs. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: Se achou a resposta útil, pode dar ao menos um upvote para valorizar o esforço. Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado Sam, sua resposta ja me ajudou conhecer o flex: 1, usava dessa forma somente no RN. kkkk

Comment: Jura que a minha resposta não merece ao menos um voto positivo?